# Django Form field initial value when updating an instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a custom Django ModelForm that I use to update a model instance.
This is the example model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(_("Number"), max_length=30, unique=True)
    sent_date = models.DateField(_('Sent date'), null=True, blank=True)
```

When creating an instance I will pass only the `number` field, that is why I don't want the `sent_date` to be required.

Then I have a view that updates the `sent_date` field, using this custom form:

```
# Generic form updater
class MyModelUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make fields mandatory
        if hasattr(self, 'required_fields'):
            for field_name in self.required_fields:
                self.fields[field_name].required = True
        # Set initial values
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_values'):
            for field_name, value in self.initial_values.items():
                self.initial[field_name] = value


class SentForm(MyModelUpdateForm):
    required_fields = ['sent_date']
    initial_values = {'sent_date': datetime.date.today()}

    class Meta(MyModelUpdateForm.Meta):
        fields = ['sent_date']
        field_classes = {'sent_date': MyCustomDateField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`MyModelUpdateForm` is a generic ancestor for concrete forms like `SentForm`.

In my view whenever there is a GET I manually instantiate the form with:

```
my_form = SentForm({instance: my_model_instance})
```

So in this case I would expect the `sent_date` field to have an initial value set to today's date even tough the real model instance field is None.

If I inspect `my_form` object it does indeed have these attributes:

```
initial: {'sent_date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 1)}
instance: my_model_instance
fields: {'sent_date':
            ...: ...,
            'initial': None # Why this is None?
            ...: ... 
         }
```

So apparently it should work but it doesn't: the field is always empty.

So I suspect that the value is coming from `my_model_instance.sent_date` that is in fact `None`.

The `initial['sent_date'] = datetime.date(2018, 3, 1)` is correct.
On the other side `fields['sent_date']['initial'] = None` it's not.

How can I always show the `initial` value when `my_model_instance.sent_date` is `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I've solved with:

```
class MyModelUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        if hasattr(self, 'initial_values') and not kwargs.get('data'):
            for field_name, value in self.initial_values.items():
                if not getattr(kwargs.get('instance', None), field_name, None):
                    initial[field_name] = value
            kwargs.update({'initial': initial})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make fields mandatory
        if hasattr(self, 'required_fields'):
            for field_name in self.required_fields:
                self.fields[field_name].required = True
```

Even tough it works I wouldn't mind a less **hackish** solution if anyone has any :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this case in many places in my app without having any problem. However, I use a different way to set up initial value of some fields of an existing instance. Instead of:

```
self.initial[field_name] = value
```

I write, after having called `super()`:

```
self.fields[field_name].initial = value
```

Can you try and tell the result ?

Comment: I wish this worked because it looks more clean and I have tried but I had no luck. After I do this the `form.fields[field_name].initial` is set correctly but `form.initial[form_name]` is None. With this solution my field always appear empty :\